# n+from which+infinitive+n

Tags: relative-clauses

> Some examples of these exceptions include the possibility of reinforcing deluded beliefs and exacerbating guilt and worry, actually constituting psychopathological expression (through excessive ritual, glossolalia, delusions of persecution or reference, etc.), or perpetuating mental illness by providing a structured framework  **from which to interpret the pathological symptoms in ways that** preclude seeking treatment for the disorder.

Could the bold part restated like this?

> "by which, pathological symptoms will be interpreted in ways that..."

If yes, which one is more familiar, and if no, is there any more familiar way to restate the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be restated that way, however I think dropping the 'from which' is fine as well, and it is probably the most familiar.

> "by providing a structured framework to interpret the pathological symptoms in ways that..."